# Visual Studio 2010 - Can't generate a solution in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio with C#. My solution can be generated in debug, but when i try to generate the solution in "release" mode some errors appear saying that it can't find some references..
[image]

The type or namespace "SAPbobsCOM" is unreacheable

I have check the configurations below:
[image]

[image]

Any idea? Why does it work in debug but not in release?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you placed the thrid party SAPbobsCOM dll in the bin/debug folder when and then added it as a referene? this could be causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Try out release with x86 mode and then try it with x64.

It may possible that external reference might have some issues with platform versions.

Hope helps.

Comment: Is it a COM component? If it is then you need to copy component in local bin directory and give reference from it. Also register component with regsvr32 utility

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192862/activex-component-cannot-be-created-for-com-component-in-release-mode-vs2010-sp

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem several times before it usually relates to one of the projects been in client profile:

see [Unable to use namespace after referencing assemblys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200460/unable-to-use-namespace-after-referencing-assemblys)

Comment: Thanks but I am using .NET 3.5 and not .NET 3.5 clientprofile. So i till dont have a solution.

Comment: did you check all your projects?

Answer (score 0):

Okay the solution was simple.

1. Select Release mode
2. Remove all the references that are not accessible
3. Add again these references
4. Clean the solution
5. Generate the solution

Well I think it is a bug, I dont know why I had to do this but now it works.